# How is the "access instance pattern" named really

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I am just refactoring some project using a pattern "I made up". I am sure there is some cool name for it - do you know which one it is?

Btw, I know its not the best way, but to reduced entaglement and get at least SOME control in the code (fast, like 900+ classes, got one day) I can live with "half ugly stuff" which cant break anything :-)

```
public class PreferenceSetter {
private static PreferenceSetter accessLimitClass = new PreferenceSetter();


private PreferenceSetter() {

}




public static void setPreferenceBoolean(APP_PREFERENCE key, Boolean value) {

    RealPrefClass.setPreferenceBoolean(key, value, accessLimitClass);
}
```

Comment: You have a class named `APP_PREFERENCE`? WHY?

Comment: Trust me, in this code is so much bad stuff, this is my smallest problem. We are talking about App.getInstance() in Android with this.instance = setByItself...  Horrible, but hey, we all started once, and the app is working. But it was time for cleanup :-)

Comment: Can I make a suggestion? Wrap the static class with a non static class that conforms to an interface. Static classes are notoriously bad when it comes to testing as you cannot create a mock or a fake. However if you wrap your static classes in a class that implements an interface you can replace it with a mock class that implements the same interface and that way it makes testing the class that uses it a heap easier. Statics are evil because you cannot do this. If you have a static class that accesses the database you end up having to create a new database just to run a test. Bad, bad, bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `proxy`?

"The proxy design pattern makes the clients of a component
communicate with a representative rather than to the component
Itself. Introducing such a placeholder can serve many purposes,
including enhanced efficiency, easier access and **protection from
unauthorized access**."